# Xamarin Android | UI shows up blank in device

Tags: visual-studio, layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing android app for learning purpose. I've installed **Xamarin 4.2.1.60** on my laptop.
I created a simple Layout and tried to run it on my **One Plus 3 (Android M 6.0.1)** and **Moto G (Android L 5.1) 1st Gen** 
but the layout shows up empty in both of them. 
It also gives me a below Exception on running:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

On pressing break, a window open in Visual Studio with Header saying Source Not Available
(Please see attached screenshots)

Please suggest how can I resolve this.

***Designer Screen:***

[image: Designer Screen]

***Device Screen:***

[image: Device Screen]

***Exception Window:***
[image: Exception Window]

Comment: Did you have any code behind? And can you show the Main.amxl  and MainActivity code to me?

Comment: Did you ensure to set `SetContentView()` in your `MainActivity.OnCreate()`? It does seem that you might be executing code that has not be instantiated and thus it could be crashing before that.

Comment: @JonDouglas Spot on!! For some reason this line was commented by default. I feel silly for overlooking such an obvious thing. Thanks. If you'll post your comment as answer, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set a default `SetContentView()` in your `MainActivity.OnCreate()` with a valid Android layout.